Error concerning projectile motion in respected textbook?
In the textbook Fundamentals of Physics by R. Shankar of Yale Open Courses, appears the following assertion pertaining to a car driving off a cliff, which seems correct:

This is exactly how long it would take to hit the ground had it simply toppled
over the edge from rest. The horizontal velocity does not delay the crash one bit
(unless you take into account the curvature of the earth).

However, at a later point in the book, Shankar makes the following claim about a bullet fired horizontally from a gun:

The bullet hits the ground at
point 1, under the pull of gravity. If you fire another bullet at a greater velocity it
will land a little further away, at point 2. While greater initial speed will extend
the time of flight even on a flat earth, the flight is further enhanced by the earth
curving under the bullet.

The claim that "While greater initial speed will extend the time of flight even on a flat earth..." seems to contradict the the initial claim.
Is this a blatant error on the part of the textbook?
Here is a link to the book if anybody is curious.

This indeed seems to be an error on the author's part. If the earth is flat and we assume a constant acceleration under gravity, the time an object takes to hit the ground must only depend on the initial VERTICAL velocity. This is because the vertical motion is independent of the horizontal motion and the only force on the object is in the vertical direction. Furthermore, even if the acceleration under gravity is taken to vary with height , this will still be true. I think the author meant that higher initial horizontal velocity enhances the length of the flight and not the time.

I think that it is a typo - While greater initial speed will extend the distance of flight even on a flat earth.

@RatulThakur But why did you post this as a comment instead of an answer?

I took the liberty to email Professor Shankar, who has confirmed the erratum below. :)

Now also confirmed in the errata https://campuspress.yale.edu/rshankar/files/2024/07/Errata_Expanded-_edition-1.pdf

If precision is important, it's actually the other way around: Seen from the bullets perspective it will be shorter time in the air due to time dilation caused by the increased speed...

I agree that the statement I made in the book is wrong: On a flat earth the time of flight is not affected by the initial horizontal velocity, only the horizontal distance is. I will post a correction in the errata in the website.
Thank you for bringing this to my attention.
R.Shankar
Yale

The errata has been edited as claimed https://campuspress.yale.edu/rshankar/files/2024/07/Errata_Expanded-_edition-1.pdf

As @RatulThakur points out, this is pretty clearly an error. ToF is not affected at all by horizontal velocity on a flat Earth, unless you're considering the aerodynamics of the object (there's a reason why planes need to stay at a certain speed).

*ToF on a flat earth. On a round earth (or even more arbitrary shapes) "horizontal" velocity does of course have an effect

@Tristan The book already mentions that adjustment in both places.

@Barmar yes, but the answer makes an incorrect claim ("ToF is not affected at all by horizontal velocity, unless you're considering the aerodynamics of the object") by not also including that requirement

@Tristan Because they're only addressing the error in the book, not the correct part about curvature.

@Barmar yes, but the answer is still incorrect as it stands because it appears to make a general claim without making explicit that it is restricting itself to the situation in the book (and assuming this takes place over a flat plane). It would be improved by making the restriction explicit

@Tristan is correct. I would assume that, in the general case, we aren't talking about an object moving at such velocity that the curvature of the Earth is apparent. Usually projectile motion like this is talked about in entry-level physics classes, and the curvature is neglected, but technically this does only apply for a flat Earth.

@Tristan Sufficient velocity makes the ToF infinite :-).
